# How to get message author id in discord.py? - Discord Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message, author

Problem is, if i try to use message.author.id, it will say

> "Cannot find reference 'author' in 'message.py'

Basically what i want to do in the code bellow is: a command that only certain id's have access to and that they can use to give their role away to someone.

Thanks for any help!

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has(939236844137226290)
async def asteroid(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    if  message.author.id == 939236844137226290:
        role = ctx.guild.get_role(939236844137226290)
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has received {role} from {ctx.author.name}!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Only asteroidblues has permission to give the role away")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you imported `discord.Message` but you have to use `message.author.id` when `message` is a variable containing a `discord.Message` instance, which you don't have in this case. But what you do have is `ctx`, the context, from which you can access the author id by using `ctx.author.id`.

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe it was such an easy fix.